# Check connection if app is close in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm building an app on Flutter that can work offline and online. The problem that I have is how can I check if the internet conection has returned even if the app is close. The app is using provider and connectivity.

Comment: Use Connectivity package

Comment: I'm already using the package conectivity, the thing is I need to listen to the connection status while the app is closed

Comment: why you need to check for the connectivity when your app is closed; Is your app running in background??